# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when running spring app in docker app in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spring, docker, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to deploy my spring app in a docker to PCF.  The docker image is one that I've built and runs just fine outside of PCF.

I can run the same docker image locally connecting to the same config server.  The config server is the only configuration provided when starting the app either locally or in PCF.

The same application runs just fine in PCF also when just deployed as a jar rather than a docker image.

The class with the problem is:

```java
@Component
@EnableRabbit
@Slf4j
class ListenerProblemListener extends Listener {

    @Autowired
    ListenerProblemListener(ErrorServiceConfiguration errorServiceConfiguration,
                            MessageQueueLibrary messageQueueLibrary,
                            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory,
                            ProblemService problemService,
                            Sender sender) {
        super(cachingConnectionFactory, messageQueueLibrary, problemService, sender)
        log.info("Connecting to queues ${errorServiceConfiguration.allProblemQueues}")
    }
}
```

I get the following exception only when attempting this in PCF.

```
2019-10-14T11:29:49.795-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [WARN ] 2019-10-14 16:29:49.794 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'listenerProblemListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/identifix/crawlererrorservice/listener/ListenerProblemListener.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when running in docker in PCF I needed to set the env var SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST.  I'm not sure why providing it in the config server wasn't enough yet.